# Codeigniter v3.0 Flashdata Session not expiring in PHP 7.4 and XAMPP 8.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, continuous-integration

Is the ***Flashdata Session*** of **Codeigniter v3** not supported in *PHP v7.3* and up? I also have *XAMPP v8.0*. This flashdata session was working and auto clears after I redirect or refresh the page with *PHP v7.2* and *XAMPP v5*.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using XAMPP 8.0 your PHP version must have been upgraded. Check if you have PHP v8.x.x. There's a change in string to number comparison in PHP v8 and it's causing this issue. It might get fixed in CI 3.1.2 but till then there's a fix available. If you find that you are using PHP v8, follow this link https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/pull/6013